# Is it possible to run maven build with java 6 together with dependency, which compiled with java 7?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-toolchains-plugin

I'm trying to run maven build with java 6, but unfortunately I have one dependency in my pom file, that compiled with java 7.

Is it possible to fix **without** java upgrade?

Thanks.

Comment: No. If the lib requires Java 7 you have to install it

Comment: what is your java 7 dependency from the pom.xml ?

Comment: This attempt will fail at compile time.  Even if it somehow passes the build, it will break when you run it.  You either need to replace your Java 7 dependency with a Java 6 version, or upgrade to Java 7.

Comment: Even if this dependency was compiled with java 7?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't. For dependencies which require java 7 to run, you must have at least java 7 in maven.

Comment: Simply wrong cause there is the possibility to use toolchain for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure [Maven Toolchain](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) to handle that. so you decouple the JDK version which is used for Maven from the one you need to compile your classes with and which the tests can be run with.